# Since iOS 12.4 iframe can't change top url

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, redirect, iframe

Since some days and I think since iOS 12.4 the browsers on iPhone are not anymore able to redirect the top frame from an iframe.
Do you know if something has been changed?

**Code from top frame (Domain 1) index.htm**

```
<iframe src='https://www.domain2.com/test.htm' id='blubb' ></iframe>
```

**Code from iframe (Domain 2) test.htm**

```
<script> top.location.href="https://www.domain1.com/somefile.htm";</script>
```

Unfortunatyle I can't see the console/error message as I have no Mac. But the redirect is not done. On other browsers/OS it works normally.
Any idea?

Comment: Adding sandbox='allow-top-navigation allow-scripts' to the iframe solves the problem, but this does not help me as I can't change the top frame source on all places

Answer (score 2):

Ugh, please forgive me for posting this as an answer- I would rather add it as a comment but I don't have the necessary 50 karma required for commenting.

I have been experiencing the same issue with iOS 12.4 and I believe it is related to some security changes in WebKit.

I have been getting the following error: 'The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is cross-origin and the user has never interacted with the frame.' 
Which I believe is originating from WebKit as seen in here: https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/dom/Document.cpp

So I'm thinking a possible solution would be to have a button that the user clicks inside the iframe to allow the navigation.

Also, you mentioned that you tried this on other browsers on a phone that has iOS 12.4, so its working for you in Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. Meanwhile I found out the same with the Mac of my colleauge and we „solved“ by asking the user to click a button. Not nice but the only solution. I wonder to not find any information/changelog about this change. But good to not be totally alone :-)
Yes it occurs also in Chrome (the iOS App) but I also learned meanwhile that iOS browsers share/are jailed to Apple rendering engine.